# Jquery Calculating sum of values from checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Sorry for my poor english !
I work on a e-shop website. For one product, i have a product price and i want to purpose 2 options by clicking checkboxes.

While one or two checkboxes are enabled, i do the sum by my jquery script without any problem and show the sum into a div called #prixtt.
But how can i hide my #prixtt if no checkbox is checked ? I don't want to display my product price ($prixactuel)!

Here is the code.

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
var total=<?php echo $prixactuel; ?>;
$('input:checked:enabled').each(function(index) {
      total += parseInt(this.value);
});
var total= total/100;
var str = ""+total;
var resultat = str.replace(".",",");
$("#prixtt").html('= '+resultat+' €');
```

});

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `.toggle(switch)` at this context,

```
$("#prixtt").toggle($('input:checked:enabled').length > 0);
```

Comment: @FrançescoMacchi Glad to help.! And by the show your acceptance to the future visitors of this post by clicking on the tick mark present with this answer. This is not a compulsion.. :) Its a simple protocol being followed here in stackoverflow.